# How to clear cookie through WinINet function?

Tags: cookies, wininet

Using `WinINet` `InternetGetCookie` and `InternetSetCookie` functions, it's pretty straightforward to get and set cookie inside the application which makes a web request through `WinINet`.

However, I could not so far find a way to clear cookie.

Calling `InternetSetCookie` with blank data (either `L""` or `NULL`) does not help (tried both with and without specifying the cookie name).

Tried `FindFirst/NextUrlCacheGroup`, `DeleteUrlCacheGroup`, and also `FindFirst/NextUrlCacheEntry`, `DeleteUrlCacheEntry` combinations. Still no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Kei,

I had the same problem and a colleague of mine just helped me solve it. You need to call:

```
InternetSetOption(0, 42, NULL, 0);
```

The answer is taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/76a38eee-3ef6-4993-a54d-3fecc4eb6cff).

This did the trick for my app and I hope it will work for you also.

**Edit:**
The "42" value in the function call stands for the "INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION" flag, which "Flushes entries not in use from the password cache on the hard disk drive. Also resets the cache time used when the synchronization mode is once-per-session. No buffer is required for this option. This is used by InternetSetOption." ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

Comment: Naturally, the answer is 42.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old post, but I thought I'd add in my findings since I'm running into a similar issue - to clear a cookie, you need to set it's expiration date to a date in the past.  This works for session cookies too:

InternetSetCookie("http://someurl.com", "mycookie" "somevalue;expires=Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT");

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Exclude..." button on the "Internet Properties" dialog box (General tab).

[image: Internet properties / General tab]

Select only the checkbox "Cookies and site data". Use the API Monitor (http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) to monitor the dialog box "Delete browse history"

[image: Delete browser History]

See what is done and execute the same thing using the Windows API functions presented. I found the solution that way